# unexpected results of join and count in jpa query

Tags: mysql, join, eclipselink, jpql

I want to retrieve the count of tags used among all posts for a specific user.
e.g. If one user has three posts written and for two posts are tagged with 'someTag', then the query should written the count as 2 for tag 'someTag'

There is one to many relationship between user and post.
There is many to many relationship between post and tag
I am using eclipseLink for jpa
I wrote this jpa query for it as follows

```
SELECT COUNT(tag.tagName)  FROM Post post, Tag tag JOIN tag.posts posts WHERE post.user = :user AND tag.tagName = :tagName
```

But this is giving me the multiplication of tag and all the posts
I have tagged 9 posts with the tag as 'friends and I have total 17 posts and the result I am getting is 153 i.e. their multiplication.

I tried a simple mysql query as follows

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Tag t
JOIN post_tag pt ON pt.idTag = t.idtag
JOIN Post p ON pt.idpost = p.idpost
JOIN User u ON p.iduser = u.iduser
WHERE u.username = 'prasadkharkar'
AND t.tagName = 'friends'
```

This works fine and gives me the result as 9.

I want the result like this in my jpa query. Can you please explain me what wrong thing I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By selecting from post AND from tag, you're doing a cartesian product. Just do as in your SQL query, and use joins:

```
select count(tag.tagName) 
from Tag tag
join tag.posts post 
where post.user = :user 
and tag.tagName = :tagName
```

Comment: Hey, thanks man, that worked :)
Can you please suggest me some links and books to study jpa query language well? That will be much appreciated

Again thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Not really. I learnt with the Hibernate manual and with the JPA specifications.